# Прекратить, прервать выполнения запроса

Tags: javascript

```js
fetch('/ajax/', {body: FormAdd(pr), method: 'POST'}).then(r => r.json()).then(d => eval(d))
```

Пользователь в текстовое поле вводит текст, с каждым набранным символом, отправляется запрос на подгрузку схожего контента

Собственно как прервать запрос `fetch()`,так чтобы не было таких случаев.

**Например при удалении**:

Удалили строчку длиною 29 символов через delete.
Строчка пуста, а окно схожих запросов по прежнему моргает по мере прихода ответов от сервера.

Comment: [Почитайте здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-abort)

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, получилось или у Вас остались какие то вопросы?

Comment: если есть какие-то замечания - напишите под ответом. Если все ок, то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делается это с помощью AbortController.

```js
// создаем контроллер
let controller = new AbortController();
// через секунду прерываем запрос
setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 1000);

try {
    fetch( '/ajax/',
        {
            body: FormAdd(pr),
            method: 'POST',
            signal: controller.signal // пробрасываем signal, ответственный за прерывание запроса
        })
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(d => eval(d));
} catch(err) {
    if (err.name == 'AbortError') { // перехватывает прерывание запроса
        alert("Aborted!");
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Подробнее см:

- https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-abort
- https://javascript.info/fetch-abort